# Mapserver - WFS and Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, mapserver

I would like create wfs with clustered layer, but something is wrong. I don't know.

When I comment out the cluster part, so it is right.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Tom

**Result:**

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://10.0.20.63/cgi-bin/mapserv.fcgi?map=/mapfiles/ismsNew/maps/cs.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAME=cs_odvodnovaci&OUTPUTFORMAT=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.1.1 http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Null>missing</gml:Null>
</gml:boundedBy>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**Url:**

http://10.0.20.63/cgi-bin/mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/mapfiles/ismsNew/maps/cs.map&LAYERS=cs_odvodnovaci&TYPENAME=cs_odvodnovaci&REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image%2Fgif&TRANSPARENT=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A102067&sld_version=1.1.0&BBOX=-625471.1678513326,-1172758.4397212453,-547287.2718699161,-1094574.5437398287

**Mapfile:**

```
MAP

NAME cs
STATUS ON
TRANSPARENT true
SIZE 800 600
EXTENT 1346035 6199272 2099395 6630666     #-920000 -1265700 -410000 -890400 
UNITS meters
FONTSET "../inc/fontset.txt"
SYMBOLSET "../inc/symbol_vumop60.sym"
CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "/usr/share/proj/"
CONFIG "ON_MISSING_DATA" "IGNORE"


PROJECTION
  "init=epsg:5514"
END

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wfs_title"          "Název WFS" ## REQUIRED
      "wfs_srs"            "EPSG:5514" ## Recommended
      "wfs_enable_request" "*"  # necessary
    END
  END  #WEB

OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME png
  DRIVER "AGG/PNG"
  MIMETYPE "image/png"
  IMAGEMODE RGB
  EXTENSION "png"
END

OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME "png8"
  DRIVER "AGG/PNG8"
  MIMETYPE "image/png; mode=8bit"
  IMAGEMODE RGB
  EXTENSION "png"
END

OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME gif
  DRIVER "GD/GIF"
  MIMETYPE "image/gif"
  IMAGEMODE PC256
  EXTENSION "gif"
  FORMATOPTION "INTERLACE=ON"
END

OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME jpeg
  DRIVER "AGG/JPEG"
  MIMETYPE "image/jpeg"
  EXTENSION "jpg"
  IMAGEMODE RGB
  FORMATOPTION "QUALITY=90"
END


LEGEND
  KEYSIZE 30 15
  STATUS ON
  LABEL
    TYPE truetype
    FONT opensanssemibold
    SIZE 8
    ANTIALIAS true
    COLOR 80 80 80
    POSITION LR
  END
END   #LEGEND

QUERYMAP
  COLOR 255 0 0
  #STYLE normal
END

LAYER

  NAME cs_odvodnovaci
  TYPE point
  CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
  INCLUDE '../inc/config63.map'
  DATA "the_geom FROM (
            SELECT gid, the_geom, a.kod, arch_c,  popis, rok_vyst, c_zakl_pr
            FROM isms.meliorace_bod_geom a

            JOIN isms.cerpaci_stanice b ON a.idn = b.idn
            JOIN isms.kod_cis c ON c.kod = a.kod

            WHERE a.kod = 'ZV401')
        AS polygon USING UNIQUE gid USING SRID=102067"
  PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
  STATUS OFF
  TEMPLATE "dummy" 
  PROCESSING "CLUSTER_GET_ALL_SHAPES"

  METADATA
    "gml_include_items" "all" ## Optional (serves all attributes for layer)
    "wfs_enable_request" "*"
      "gml_geometries"    "geometry"    
      "gml_geometry_type" "point"  
      END

  SYMBOLSCALEDENOM 50000  
  LABELITEM "Cluster:FeatureCount"
  CLASSITEM "Cluster:FeatureCount"
  SYMBOLSCALEDENOM 50000 

  ###########################
 # Define the cluster object
 ###########################
  CLUSTER
    MAXDISTANCE 50
    REGION "ellipse"
  END

  ################################
  # Class1: For the cluster symbol
  ################################
  CLASS
    #NAME "cluster"
    EXPRESSION ("[Cluster:FeatureCount]" > "1")

    STYLE
      SYMBOL "box"
      MINSIZE 28
      MAXSIZE 35
      COLOR 250 180 160
      OUTLINECOLOR 50 50 50
      WIDTH 0.5
    END
    LABEL
      FONT arialbold
      TYPE TRUETYPE
      MINSIZE 13
      MAXSIZE 13
      COLOR 0 0 0
      ALIGN CENTER
      OFFSET 0 0
      PRIORITY 10
      BUFFER 1
      PARTIALS TRUE
      POSITION cc
    END
  END

  ################################
  # Class1: For the unique symbol
  ################################  

  CLASS
    NAME 'čerpací stanice odvodňovací'

    EXPRESSION ("[gid]")
    STYLE
      SYMBOL "box"
      MINSIZE 12
      MAXSIZE 15
      COLOR 250 180 160
      OUTLINECOLOR 50 50 50
      WIDTH 0.5
    END
  END  

END

END  #MAP
```

Comment: Your URL is a complete mess are you after WMS providing images (`FORMAT=image%2Fgif&` and `TRANSPARENT=true&` and SLD...) and acting on layers (`LAYERS=cs_odvodnovaci&`) or WFS providing raw vector data (`TYPENAME=cs_odvodnovaci&` and `REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&`)

Comment: Generally clustering of data happens in a WMS, a way of creating map images based on some input vector (point) data.  With a WFS you get the raw data, and it's up to you to come up with a strategy to cluster the data in your client.